# ModelMapper: Map geometries as GeoJson

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, geojson, modelmapper

I just found ModelMapper and I've found it very useful to generate DTOs.

Anyway, when it comes to serialize objects which own a JTS Geometry data type attribute, I'd want them to be in GeoJson format.

For the time being, the following class...

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.MultiPolygon;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Table(name = "municipios")
@Builder
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Municipio implements Serializable {

    /*
     * Atributos
     */
    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2486158354849124667L;

    @Id
    private Integer gid;
    private String codigo;
    private String texto;
    private MultiPolygon geom;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "cod_prov", 
            referencedColumnName = "codigo"
        )
    private Provincia provincia;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "cod_ccaa", 
            referencedColumnName = "codigo"
        )
    private ComunidadAutonoma comunidad;

}
```

...gets serialized as this...

```
    "municipio": {
    "gid": 27,
    "codigo": "01036",
    "texto": "Laudio/Llodio",
    "provincia": {
        "gid": 1,
        "codigo": "01",
        "texto": "Álava",
        "texto_alt": "Araba",
        "comunidad": {
            "gid": 16,
            "codigo": "16",
            "texto": "País Vasco",
            "texto_alt": "Euskadi"
        }
    },
    "geom": "MULTIPOLYGON (((-2.9420491414616916 43.14380029306756, -2.9408165999002556 43.14430841999599, -2.939059950482368 43.141709610211024, -2.94050966386134 43.13799144046195, -2.936693413950487 43.13417138986535, -2.942182362664065 43.130752517734585, -2.943746497171919 43.126998320661244, -2.9491831049375983 43.122917261507745, -2.9568712631986553 43.11281715256084, -2.958883438671909 43.11305654097181, -2.9659615390025005 43.103108652799214, -2.9652067663290955 43.10264468267702, -2.9762492404051137 43.097150217253514, -2.9899968551814102 43.1013215781132, -2.9963369436287586 43.10706705889331, -3.0097035041930043 43.11278484125608, -3.0129149314121726 43.116877214910765, -3.017330715593204 43.116457973261085, -3.019790265011745 43.11919501110562, -3.02040901781778 43.12611504150391, -3.02393972418118 43.12847813412591, -3.025215180146138 43.13126035313113, -3.021643236846659 43.137154623532716, -3.013836762498057 43.1408026665335, -3.005568207272493 43.148466258438624, -3.0026147541242167 43.14959643860667, -2.9909328393119017 43.1625087272497, -2.9796315563151357 43.17050333013982, -2.9766664577130144 43.17485199744999, -2.9736646499823842 43.17600841462698, -2.979262791265818 43.18166902950952, -2.9742758156428035 43.18436486223879, -2.97110139733367 43.18276575229797, -2.969942290790593 43.179992017776314, -2.961893498167311 43.17338464369854, -2.957182021700495 43.17193318237574, -2.955167271064855 43.170041426431084, -2.9475444948015594 43.16848931161088, -2.955018585037522 43.157632918409604, -2.9474297891472103 43.151515433493785, -2.9420491414616916 43.14380029306756)))"
}
```

Is there any way to tell ModelMapper to map Geometries as GeoJSON objects when it comes to serializing objects?

Comment: where do you hold coordinates for "geom" in Municipio entity?

Comment: @AndrewNepogoda thanks, I just removed the attribute when removing unnecessary comments. There you're.

Comment: okay, now I see that it is possible to map with modelmapper.

Comment: It should be an straightforward task, but I don't know how to wire up ModelMapper's Jackson ObjectMapper class with [this](https://github.com/opendatalab-de/geojson-jackson) or [this](https://github.com/bedatadriven/jackson-datatype-jts)

Comment: I am not familiar with GeoJSON objects. Which part of your model(Municipio) directly mapping to GeoJSON objects? Only geom? You want to map to dto which contains GeoJSON objects besides plain properties, am i right?

Comment: If I've understood you well, yes, what I want is to map the `private Geometry geom` attribute as a GeoJSON in the DTO object, so that geom look like a Json object rather than a plain Geometry (as seen above)